# How to apply css to text inside an ionic alert?

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, alert

I have an alert where I have some text and one ionicon and I want to change its color and adjust its size and position (center) and I created a css class tried to apply it but it doesn't work, even thought HTML seems to work, I used the `<b>` tag just fine.
My code:

```
async presentAlertError(data) {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Confirmation',
      message: '<ion-icon name="close" class="custom-icon-notfound" > </ion-icon>'  + "Registration " + data.statusText,
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (aux) => {
            console.log('Confirm Cancel: aux');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Scan Next',
          handler: () => {
            this.scanCode();
            console.log('Confirm ');
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    await alert.present()
```

Should I do this in a different way?

Comment: the secondary class is added to the text element on mine fine, could you show the CSS your trying to add?

Comment: the css is .custom-icon-notfound {color: red}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ion-alert isnt displayed in the home page or (whatever page/component you have the alert on) shadow DOM so styling wont affect it if you add it there, you have to add the styles to an element which is in the same scope as the alert. I added the class to variables.scss as that has the highest scope:

variables.scss-

```
   .secondary {
            color: #A0A !important;
            font-size: 2em !important;
        }

   .custom-icon-notfound {color: red}
```

[image]

also need added !important so it ignores its previous styling.

Comment: I do have this in the css of home (this is the home component so it's on the correct associated file) my worry is that it wont work since this html on the message, is made programatically and I am hadding html on the text message and on top of it a css class. but is this the correct way to go about it?

Comment: Sorry thought the question was about the 'secondary' class. The way you've done this is fine should render on ios and android fine. If I did it I might add the icon as a class on the message as opposed to embedding html in the message but I dont see it being an issue.

Comment: now that I think about it your using icons from ionic. honestly don't think there's any other way of doing this other than the way you've done. have you got it to work ?

Comment: thanks this has worked for me, moving th css to the variables.scss, this file is in the location src/themes, if anyone ever needs this  as well :)

Comment: @AntWo Works also in global.scss